# Duplicating a Name and assigning a number based off a cell quantity

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I am runninga fundraiser and am trying take a report that shows the number of tickets purchased by an individual for a specific item. I want to be able to assign a paper ticket number for each individula ticket sold in a chronological order. I have the starting ticket number and would like the sheet ot assing the next number up without manually entering them.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  This site fixes code and thus questions must contain code to be fixed, otherwise its a guessing game on trying to help.   Update with pertenant code so someone can try to help you.  Good luck!